# How to use ".find()" with an array in vuejs

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, socket.io

I have the following code on my project components:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <agent
      v-for="agent in agents"
      :uuid="agent.uuid"
      :key="agent.uuid"
      :socket="socket">
    </agent>
    <p v-if="error">{{error}}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<style>
  body {
    font-family: Arial;
    background: #f8f8f8;
    margin: 0;
  }
</style>

<script>
const request = require('request-promise-native')
const io = require('socket.io-client')
const { serverHost } = require('../config')
const socket = io()
module.exports = {
  data () {
    return {
      agents: [],
      error: null,
      socket
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.initialize()
  },
  methods: {
    async initialize () {
      const options = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: `${serverHost}/agents`,
        json: true
      }
      let result
      try {
        result = await request(options)
      } catch (e) {
        this.error = e.error.error
        return
      }
      this.agents = result
      socket.on('agent/connected', payload => {
        const { uuid } = payload.agent
        const existing = this.agents.find(a => a.uuid === uuid)
        if (!existing) {
          this.agents.push(payload.agent)
        }
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

It seems everything is working fine, however, when I get an agent connected the following line is complaining...

```
 const existing = this.agents.find(a => a.uuid === uuid)
```

message in the console sais 'Uncaught TypeError: n.agents.find is not a function'

I don't see where is the bug... any help?
Thanks a million

UPDATE -> this is what I have in "result":

```
{…}
agentMAC: (...)
agentName: (...)
connected: (...)
createdAt: (...)
id: (...)
lastAccess: (...)
loginDate: (...)
pid: (...)
updatedAt: (...)
userId: (...)
__ob__: Ae {value: {…}, dep: fe, vmCount: 0}
get agentMAC: ƒ ()
set agentMAC: ƒ (t)
get agentName: ƒ ()
set agentName: ƒ (t)
get connected: ƒ ()
set connected: ƒ (t)
get createdAt: ƒ ()
set createdAt: ƒ (t)
get id: ƒ ()
set id: ƒ (t)
get lastAccess: ƒ ()
set lastAccess: ƒ (t)
get loginDate: ƒ ()
set loginDate: ƒ (t)
get pid: ƒ ()
set pid: ƒ (t)
get updatedAt: ƒ ()
set updatedAt: ƒ (t)
get userId: ƒ ()
set userId: ƒ (t)
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: What is the value of `result`?

Comment: try with replace find with filter.

Comment: Same as str, `this.agents = result` are you sure result is an array?

Comment: result contains an array of object with agents. If i use typeof it display "object" but... It might be becase there is only 1 element?

I tried to replace find with filter and it didnt work...

Comment: Don't describe the value but update your question with the *actual* value that you get. It does not seem to be an array (but might be a JSON string instead). Or maybe you are using a browser from medieval times (for example Internet Explorer 11) that does not support `Array.prototype.find()`.

Comment: Following your suggestion I updated the question with value of "result". On the other hand, using Chrome last version....

Comment: That is not an array but an object. Objects don't have a `find` method.

Comment: This is 99% probability that `result` isn't an array

Answer (score 1):

From your update it looks like result value is an object and when you assign it to this.agents now it is also just an object. If the results will either be a single object or an array of objects, then it would be better to assign results as below which would make sure that it would be an array.

```
this.agents = result ? [].concat(result) : []
```

note: ternery check above will also make sure to assign empty array if result is undefined/null.

Answer (score 0):

This should be the correct method you want to use.

```
userobjectbyid: function(id) {
  var userobject = this.users.find(user => { 
      if (user.id === id) { 
        return user
        } 
        });
  return userobject;
}
```